# .htaccess RewriteRule Problem

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, .htaccess, rewrite

Before asking question let me tell you some assumptions here
there are 5 files on my webserver
index.php
config.php
read.php
write.php
.htaccess

I've wrote following URL rewriting rule in .htaccess

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(\w+)$ read.php?id=$1

Now when I type domain.com/xyz
it fetch data from read.php?id=xyz thats nice :)

But 
when I type domain.com/index
it fetch data from index.php 
or 
when i type domain.com/write or domain.com/config or domain.com/read
it fetch data from write.php , config.php and read.php respectively

I want data to be fectched from read.php?id=index or read.php?id=config or read.php?id=read or read.php?id=write

Any one can help me regarding this ?

Sorry for my poor english

Answer (score 1):

```
Options -multiviews
```

For some reason, your original rule must have a RewriteCond that checks to see if the file exists.  Since multiviews is on, and index.php does exist and you've requested index, mod_negotiation will assume you want to get index.php

Your rule will work fine with multiviews off.

Answer (score 0):

Try This.....

> RewriteEngine On RewriteRule
>   ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ read.php?id=$1

Comment: please check your other code. Just tested, It works for me fine!

Note that the code I posted above requires a "/" at end of URL. You can remove it by removing the extra "/" before the "$" sign above.

Answer (score 0):

Use
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ read.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
This way, all requests are rewritten

Comment: This is causing Internal Server Error

Comment: Could you post your complete modrewrite section which causes the internal server error ?